# Is there a way to display a list of all variables in VSCode with a small summary?

Tags: python, matlab, visual-studio-code

I am trying to convert my MATLAB programs to Python and I am using Visual Studio Code (VSCode). There is a workspace panel in the MATLAB IDE where it displays all the variables used in the code with a small summary, like what is the type of the variable or its size. Is there any way of displaying this in VSCode? Also if I double click on the variable, it opens up a panel where it displays all the values or the data in that variable.

EXAMPLE:

So, if I write a small code such as

```
I = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
P = max(I);
Q = min(I);
```

My Workspace looks like [image: MATLAB Workspace and whos command]

I can also type "whos" with a specific variable to display the details in the command window.

Also, if I double click one of the variables, it displays this

[image: MATLAB Variables pane]

Is there any way to do this in VSCode or any script in Python that I can use?

Any help is appreciated.
Thank You.

Comment: you can use the python interactive window for that

Comment: you can use [`spyder`](https://www.spyder-ide.org/) for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a look at the [Python interactive shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/python-interactive-repl-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019).

It looks like this:

[image: Python interactive window]

Answer (score 1):

You can also view a list of all available variables while debugging:

[image]

For each variable, a brief preview is displayed, from which you can understand value and/or type. You can expand complex variables such as lists and dicts to see all their elements.

By right-clicking on a variable, a "View Value in Data Viewer" option is also available, which opens a table-like viewer in the main vscode window, where you can explore your variable. This is of course best suited for lists and dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is! You can run .ipynb files inside vscode. So you can run in debug mode and a panel will show up like this: [image]